# Transpose - Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, transpose

I have a df that I would like to transpose. I keep getting an error

```
TypeError: pivot_table() got multiple values for argument 'values'
```

Could anyone guide me as to where am I going wrong.

Given below is how my dataframe is:

```
prod_name,ref_date,total_sales,payment_received,payment_not_received
prod_a,2018-01-01,100,30,70
prod_b,2018-10-01,50,10,40
prod_c,2018-10-02,10,0,50
```

I tried to perform transpose using pivot_table function

```
df.pivot_table(df, values=['total_sales','payment_received','payment_not_received'], index = ['prod_name'], columns = 'ref_date')
```

Could anyone guide me as to where am I going wrong.

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) and omit `df` inside function:

```
df.pivot_table(values=['total_sales','payment_received','payment_not_received'], 
               index = ['prod_name'], 
               columns = 'ref_date')
```

Or use [`pandas.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) -  change `df.pivot_table` to `pd.pivot_table`:

```
pd.pivot_table(df, values=['total_sales','payment_received','payment_not_received'], 
               index = ['prod_name'], 
               columns = 'ref_date')
```